# Find out if assembly is signed with Authenticode

Tags: c#, code-signing, authenticode

I use an assembly of a 3rd party vendor. In an older version this assembly used authenticode. This caused the assembly loading to last quiet long. The developer of the vendor told me that the new version is not signed with authenticode. 
How can I check if this is true. On my development machine the assembly loading was quiet fast. Only on client machines it took quiet a while. Is it possible to check this using a network sniffer?

Regards